# How do I use Navigation Properties of an Entity DataSource on a DataGridView?

Tags: winforms, entity-framework, datagridview, datasource

I have the following relationship between Entities.

Customer -> Address (Via Navigation Properties)

I am binding the Customers to a grid, but how do I display address information using the Navigation Properties? I have searched all over and can't figure it out. :(

Here is my current code. I have also tried to set the DataProperty in the Grid to "Address.Street", no luck.

```
GroomerEntities context = new GroomerEntities();

context.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;

gvCustomers.DataSource = context.Customers;
```